# Checking how many times a digit appears in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, digit

I'm trying to check how many times a digit appears in a dictionary.

This code only works if I input a single digit.

```
numbers = input("Enter numbers ")

d = {}
d['0'] = 0
d['1'] = 0
d['2'] = 0
d['3'] = 0
d['4'] = 0
d['5'] = 0
d['6'] = 0
d['7'] = 0
d['8'] = 0
d['9'] = 0

for i in numbers:
    d[numbers] += 1

print(d)
```

For example if I input `8` the output will be

```
{'8': 1, '9': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0}
```

But if I input `887655` then it gives me a `builtins.KeyError: '887655'`

If I input `887655` the output should actually be

```
{'8': 2, '9': 0, '4': 0, '5': 2, '6': 1, '7': 1, '0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably change

```
d[numbers] += 1
```

=>

```
d[i] += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this instead - no need to reinvent the wheel.

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter("887655")
Counter({'8': 2, '5': 2, '6': 1, '7': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is actually this:

```
for number in numbers:
    for digit in str(number):
        d[digit] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
numbers = input("Enter numbers: ")
count = Counter(numbers)
for c in count:
    print c, "occured", count[c], "times"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `collections.Counter` but here's an improved version of your code:

```
numbers = input("Enter numbers ")

d = {} # no need to initialize each key

for i in numbers:
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1 # we can use dict.get for that, default val of 0

print(d)
```